# What kind of singularity an entire function $f$ have at infinity provided $f^{-1}(B_{1})$ is bounded

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

What kind of singularity an entire function $f$ have at infinity provided $f^{-1}(B_{1})$ is bounded , where $B_{r}$ is a closed disk $\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z| \leq r\}$

**Solution i tried**-First i suppose an example $f(z)=z$, which satisfies all the given condiitons and it have a Pole of order $1$ at infinity

But there can be other possibility , i'm not getting how to get that,

someone recommend me to use "**Casorati–Weierstrass**" theorem , but can see how can that help in inverse of a entire function

Please Help

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can only have  a pole at $\infty$ unless it is a constant $c$ with $|c| >r$.  If it has an essential singularity then, in every neighborhood of $\infty$, the function  would assume values inside $B_1$ (by Casorati–Weierstrass theorem). If it is a removable singularity then it is a constant by Liouville's Theoem. It should  also be noted that if $f$ is entire and $f$ has a pole at $\infty$ then it is a polynomial.

Comment: so preimage of $B_1$ will be in some deleted neighbourhod of infinity , but then $f^{-1}(B_1)$ can't be bounded ,so it can't have essential singularity?, rests two can possible , am i right?

Comment: Yes that is right. But if $f$ is  a constant $c$ the we must have $|c| >r$. @honeykumar

Comment: because if  $|c| <r$ as per question $f^{-1}(B_{1})$ is bounded , but its preimage should be whole complex plane?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  @honeykumar

Comment: Thank you @Kavi Rama Murthy.